# What does it mean to say that "Haskell has only universally quantified types?"

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

While reading [this Haskell tutorial](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html), I came across this remark:

> Furthermore, since Haskell has only universally quantified types, there is no need to explicitly write out the symbol for universal quantification, and thus we simply write [a] in the example above.

What is an example of non-universally quantified types? What would that look like like? Are there programming languages which have this feature?